# INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA - PictureCallback or intercept events take a picture

Tags: android, android-intent, service, camera

I induce camera using `INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA`, I have the opportunity to do any number of photos until I press the **back**.

My  question is, can I capture single images as well as in custom camera in PictureCallback? I dont see capabilities to hook the camera to PictureCallback or can I write a service that will intercept the events that take a picture?

I know that if i use flag **ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE**, I can take image in activityResult from intent data, but it is important to take a few photo.

Currently I take image using cursor form ContentResolver after I press **back** button.

```
Cursor imageCursor =  activity.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,imageColumns, where, null, imageOrderBy);
```

but I have problem with it on Sony Erricson arc S with api 2.3.4, query doesn't work, application still work, any exception, but result of query is empty.

Answer (score 1):

[The `Camera.PictureCallback` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PictureCallback.html) is for use with [the `Camera` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html), not for use with `INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA`.